# Soluion of LTV Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me in finding solution of the LTV equation given by 
$$t\ddot{x}-\dot{x}+tx=0$$ or equivalently the LTV system 
$$\dot{x}_1 =-tx_2, \dot{x}_2 =-\frac{x_1}{t}$$.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Switch to the new variable $y={t^p}x$. Then the first order derivatives cancel (I think for $p=1/2$) and the remaining equation is of the Bessel type (if my memory serves me well).

Comment: Or if you choose $p = -1$ you get the regular Bessel equation for which the solution is well known.

Comment: Thanks guys! Actually I am looking for solution method based on fundamental and transition matrices. Would be great if anyone can share the solution method based on this technique!